# How to get value by field name in MYSQL xdevapi 8.0 connector c++

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-x-devapi

For connector c++ 1.1, in this [example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html), it's quite easy to get values by specifying the column name (or alias name).
But when I upgraded to version 8.0 xdevapi, I found this feature is no longer supported.

```
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace mysqlx;

Session sess(<server_url>);
auto result = sess.sql("SELECT * FROM student").execute();
Row row = result.fetchOne();
cout << row[0] << endl;         // <- ok
cout << row["ID"] << endl;      // <- can compile but garbage output
cout << row.get("ID") << endl;  // <- cannot compile
```

I know the column names can be retrieved from `result.getColumn(n).getColumnLabel()`, but IMO it's useless. A "field" -> "index" mapping can really help the developers.

I'm new to C++, so the following sentenses maybe too naive. Here's the possible ways I guess:

- construct a STL map to record the mapping
- iterate through the `result.getColumns()`, then check the `getColumnLabel()`
- something like `indexOf`? But I find `result.getColumns()` does not support this method since it's a `deque`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way, at the moment, to get the column value using name.

A way is, as you suggest, a map with the name / index pair.

Something like this would work:

```
SqlResult sql_res = sess.sql("select * from table").execute();

std::map<std::string, size_t> columns;
auto fill_columns = [&sql_res, &columns]() -> void
{
  size_t idx = 0;
  for (auto &el : sql_res.getColumns())
  {
    columns.emplace(std::make_pair(el.getColumnLabel(), idx++));
  }
};

fill_columns();
```

And then, using it:

```
for(auto row : sql_res)
{
  std::cout << "a:" << row[columns["a"]] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "b:" << row[columns["b"]] << std::endl;
}
```